# CommandText Property Has Not Been Initialized, retrieving data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
Private Sub ButtonSubmitID_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSubmitID.Click
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = test2Forms; Integrated Security = SSPI;"
    comm.Connection = conn
    Dim ID = TextBoxID.Text
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm.CommandText, comm.Connection)
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM withActivityLog3 WHERE ID = @ID"
    Dim records As DataSet = New DataSet
    adapter.Fill(records)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = records
End Sub
```

CommandText property has not been initialized is the error I am receiving.  I am able to pull all the data from the database into the GridView on the Form Load but when I try to narrow it down to one ID using a WHERE clause on the button trigger, it comes up with the above error.  I've used the debugger to trace through one step at a time and the command and connection strings look correct.  I've also successfully duplicated the query on my database using the SQL Server command line.  I'm searching on a primary key (ID) so the expected results would be one uniquely identified row from the database.

Comment: Look carefully at your code...you set `comm.CommandText` ***after*** you passed it (empty) to the DataAdapter.  You do not need to create a command object nor a connection object to a DataAdapter - just pass the SQL and the connection string.  Since you do want/need a DBCommand object for the parameter, you dont need the DataAdapter, just fill the datatable directly....no need for a local DataSet wither.  [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: yeah, I cant read that

Comment: Note that you can vote now (click the Up arrow) next to *any* Q or A which you find useful or informative.  As the [tour] explains voting helps others find good posts.  It is a passive way someone can participate and help others even without posting answers.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks!  I'll do that!

Comment: It was very helpful, was able to make the changes before leaving work, but not able to fully test yet.  My fault, lol, I designed the Forms to be fullscreen on a large monitor and on my laptop at home I can't get to the buttons.  I'm dying to see if this works.  It did make so much more sense to me.  I had seen the Using code before and that seems to be the best way to go.  I'm going to have to remember the DRY principal and I also liked the rubber duck debugging.  Maybe I can find someone at work to do that with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the problem you know you have:

```vb
' initialize DataAdapter with (EMPTY) commandtext
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm.CommandText, comm.Connection)
' initialize Command Text
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM withActivityLog3 WHERE ID = @ID"
```

When you pass the `CommandText` to the DataAdapter, it is empty because you havent set it yet which results in the error.

There is a fair amount of inefficiency in your code though.  Rewritten:

```vb
' form level conn string
Private TheConnString As String = "Data Source = localhost\..."

Private Sub ButtonSubmitID_Click(sender ...

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using dbcon As New MySqlConnection(TheConnString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from Sample where Id = @id", dbcon)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)
            dbcon.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

            dgvA.DataSource = dt

        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Note: this uses MySQL but the concepts are the same for Sqlite, Access, SQL Server etc

- There is no need to type or paste the connection string and over everywhere it is used.  One form level variable will allow [DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.
- Anything which implements the `Dispose()` method should be disposed of.  That includes nearly all the DB Provider objects.  The `Using` statement allows you to declare and initialize an object and at the `End Using` it is disposed of.  Failing to `Dispose` of things can cause leaks and even run out of connections or resources to create things like DB Command objects.
- There is no need to create a local `DbDataAdapter`.   These are very powerful and useful critters meant to do much more than fill a `DataTable`.  If that is all you are doing, you can use `ExecuteReader` method on the `DbCommand` object.
- Nor do you need a local `DataSet`.  Contrary to the name, these do not hold data, but `DataTables`.  Since there is only one and it is local (goes out of scope when the method ends), you dont need a `DataSet` to store it.
- The `Add` method should be used rather than `AddWithValue`.  The code above specifies the datatype for the parameter so there is no guesswork required of the compiler.  Of course with that comes the need to convert the text to a number...
- ...Since this is user input, you should not trust the user, so `Integer.Tryparse` would be more appropriate: `I like pie` will not convert to an integer.  Data Validation is something you should do before you commence the DB ops.
- `Dim ID = TextBoxID.Text` as used is pointless code.  You do not need to move the textbox text into a new variable in order to use it.  However, `ID` might be used to store the integer value